# Закрытие всех вкладок браузера

Tags: вкладки, браузер

Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста, объясните мне, *как и чем* можно закрыть **все открытые вкладки** браузера? Что для этого нужно: **js** или **php**?

Большое спасибо всем отвечающим! Действительно очень нужно решение.

Comment: А вы бы не охренели, если бы вы зашли, например, на `hashcode.ru` и у вас бы сразу закрылись все вкладки?

Comment: Котик_хочет_кушать, это не для сайта, а для расширения. Это во-первых. Во-вторых расширения для себя пишу. Так что вредить никому не собираюсь. Идею вашу понял..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если расширение для Хрома, то поможет [chrome.tabs.remove](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html).
Для FireFox искать где-то [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabs). Я не нашел, но я сильно и не старался. Думаю, должна быть такая возможность.
Для Opera читать [здесь](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/extensions-api-windows-tabs/).
Для остальных браузеров можно поискать запросом

```
browser_name extension api
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Большое спасибо за ответ, это именно то, что нужно. Прошу прощения у всех, что забыл сразу в вопросе указать, что требуется код для расширения.

Comment: Вот поэтому я давно говорил в каком-то обсуждении, что не нужно запрещать новые ответы в закрытый вопрос.  
Чувствовал себя хирургом пришивающим отрубленный палец ректально, когда постил коммент и преобразовывал его в ответ :)

Comment: ReinRaus, действительно нужная функция. Я с вами полностью согласен.

Comment: Просто не надо было закрывать вопрос :)

Answer (score 3):

На javascript:

```
alert('Нажмите ctrl+shift+w');
```

Comment: Аеаеае))
ещё вот на PHP есть:
    
    <?php
    echo "<script>alert('Нажмите ctrl+shift+w');</script>";
    ?>

Comment: Вы шутите? Зачем мне alert? И тем более ваш код, Construct.

Comment: @lwww, Шелдон, перелогиньтесь под своим аккаунтом))

Comment: Очень смешно..

Answer (score 2):

Если без шуток, то закрыть текущее окно:

```
window.close();
```

А чужое окно закрыть возможности нет. Есть возможность закрывать окна, которые были открыты в данном окне (хороший пример взят со стека):

```
var wnds = new Array();
wnds[wnds.length] = window.open();
for(i = 0; i < wnds.length; ++i)
    wnds[i].close();
```

Comment: Хотя бы так. Не совсем то, что нужно, но всё равно спасибо за "серьёзный ответ".

Comment: Ну совсем для формальности следует подытожить, что именно того, что нужно в JS по понятным причинам нет, а в PHP смотреть нечего: сервер, отправив страшное сообщение, точно вкладки закрыть не сможет.